# Correct way to set .Net MAUI MediaElement Source from Code?

Tags: .net, maui

My question: How can I correctly instantiate a MediaSource instance and/or the MediaElement using code behind so that I can:

- Programmatically set the MediaElement Source at runtime (it's a FileSource)
- Correctly call the Play function, again from code

I'm planning to hide the control as I just want to be able to selectively play short sound "effects" without a player control visible. But first....

WelcomeVoicePlayer is a named MediaElement in the PageContent xaml. I'm trying to use that element to play a sound that I set at runtime and/or change at runtime in the ContentPage code.

Approach that's not working:

```
// Neither of these approaches to setting Source worked...
var voiceFile = FileMediaSource.FromFile(tempVoicePath);
//WelcomeVoicePlayer = new MediaElement { Source = voiceFile };
        
// When Play is called I hear nothing, even though audio file is good etc...
WelcomeVoicePlayer.Play();
```

Happy to reinstantiate the control if needed for each new source, but still need to able to set Source from code.

Any clues appreciated.

Dave G

P.S. Big thanks to all those that brought the MediaElement forward to Maui!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your first option is pretty close. You might want to try this:

```cs
var voiceFile = MediaSource.FromFile(tempVoicePath);
WelcomeVoicePlayer = new MediaElement { Source = voiceFile };
```

A full example, that I have seen working myself just now is this:

```cs
var page = new ContentPage();
var stack = new VerticalStackLayout();
var mediaElement = new MediaElement
{
    ShouldAutoPlay = true,
    Source = MediaSource.FromFile("C:\\Users\\jfversluis\\Desktop\\video.mp4"),
};

stack.Children.Add(mediaElement);
page.Content = stack;

MainPage = page;
```

The one thing I would note is that filesystem access is pretty straight-forward on Windows and macOS, but on the mobile devices it might not be. There is more things to deal with like permissions or maybe files that are loaded from a cloud-provider and first need to be downloaded.

If something is not working you might want to hook up the `MediaFailed` event to get some more details on what is going wrong.

> P.S. Big thanks to all those that brought the MediaElement forward to Maui!

You're welcome!

Comment: Thanks for these good leads. I need an implementation that can load the page, and as the app is sitting there idle, assuming I've already declared a named MediaElement in the xaml markup (call it Player) with PlayerControls set to hidden, I need to able to pass either a file or stream to the Source of the existing Player MediaElement when a message arrives. The sound played changes depending on the message. I'm trying to play "different sound effects", basically, using a hidden mediaelement. May post a new question with this (better) specificity of my use case, but any ideas appreciated.

Comment: @Gerald, I note that your example adds MediaElement to the visual tree, even though David's use-case is audio only and doesn't involve UI to see or control any aspect of it. Is this a necessary step, even when visuals are not wanted?

Comment: I guess technically it isn't necessary, but `MediaElement` is built as a visual control. If you just want audio maybe Plugin.Maui.Audio is a better option.

Comment: Thanks Gerald. Don't know about OP, bur I'm playing audio only and full video at different times. My hope is to have only one media player nuget to look after. Will investigate what works and what doesn't!

Comment: Further to my previous comment, it seems it _is_ necessary to add the `MediaElement` to the visual tree. I experimented with an embedded resource mp3 and while `Source` can be successfully set, `mediaElement.Play()` has no effect unless `.Children.Add(mediaElement)` has previously been called (`mediaElement.CurrentState` doesn't change from `None` and there is no sound).

Comment: Is there a way to set the MediaElement source to a stream or a memory stream without writing the stream to a file on disk?

Answer (score 2):

The shorthand `embed://` and `filesystem://` only work from XAML. In code, please use `MediaSource.FromResource()` and `MediaSource.FromFile()` respectively.

Using these methods, you can omit the the `embed://` and `filesystem://` prefixes. The rest of the path should be the same.

This is stated in a note on the media element page [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/mediaelement?fbclid=IwAR10x83NfO5g6a8TnxfPsLujMvWli8eRodwpIUm7Prw8FSgBqejH0q5qsZ8#play-local-media)

So for you
`//WelcomeVoicePlayer.Source = MediaSource.FromResource("voicefile.mp3");`
if it is in your asset directory (Raw) and
`//WelcomeVoicePlayer.Source  = MediaSource.FromFile("path and filename");`
if it is a file somewhere on the device