# Using .Net Maui CommunityToolkit MediaElement to Play Short Sound Fx

Tags: .net, maui, mediaelement

I'm trying to play "different sound effects", basically, using a hidden MediaElement. My current approach assumes I've already declared a named MediaElement in the xaml markup for a page (call it "FxPlayer") with PlaybackControls set to hidden, something like:

`<toolkit:MediaElement x:Name="FxPlayer" MaximumHeightRequest="1" MaximumWidthRequest="1" ShouldShowPlaybackControls="False" />`

And that everything else happens in code behind, including:

- Playing audio with the MediaElement when it's host page is active, but
  only in response to a message (using WeakReferenceMessages, say).
- Using either a file or stream to set the Source of the existing
  FxPlayer when a message arrives to the page control. The sound the
  "FxPlayer" element plays changes depending on the message, which is
  why I assume a good implementation will let me use MediaSource
  instances created at runtime and used to set the Source element of
  the property whenever I want to play an "effect".

I know there will be latency and am not looking to sync to visual action, so the "fx" label is a bit strong, but gets to the point. Need an "audio channel out".

Thanks in advance, as always. ([related prior post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75525722/correct-way-to-set-net-maui-mediaelement-source-from-code/75535084#75535084))

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish and where are you stuck? I don't understand what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps you. I use this code in a Code behind and Trigger it over WeakReferenzMessenger.
Code in the Constructor of my Page:

```
WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<PlaySoundMessage>(this, (r, m) =>
{
    MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
        this.PlaySound(m.Value);
    });
});
```

Code of the Method:

```
void PlaySound(string soundname)
{
    if (!soundname.IsNullOrEmpty())
    {
        mediaElement.Source = MediaSource.FromResource(soundname);
        mediaElement.Stop();
        mediaElement.Play();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! After all that it seems that it was the addition of the Stop call before the Play call that made the difference.