# .NET MAUI, is MediaElement's "Source" attribute bindable?

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, maui, mediaelement

I'm trying to *not* hardcode the value for the `Source` attribute for the `MediaElement` using XAML ([as opposed to C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75525722/correct-way-to-set-net-maui-mediaelement-source-from-code)).

I have this code:

```
            <!-- Displays "embed://file.mp4" -->
            <Label Text="{Binding Filename}" FontSize="Large" Padding="20"/>

            <!-- Doesn't work. -->
            <toolkit:MediaElement Source="{Binding Filename}"
                                  ShouldShowPlaybackControls="True"
                                  Aspect="AspectFill" />

            <!-- Has SAME VALUE, but does work -->
            <toolkit:MediaElement Source="embed://file.mp4"
                                  ShouldShowPlaybackControls="True"
                                  Aspect="AspectFill"/>
```

I guess that the `Source` attribute isn't "bindable" or something (I'm sorry I'm new here).  But if it's not bindable, then what are devs supposed to do?

If the answer's in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/mediaelement#play-local-media), then I can't find it.

---

EDIT: of course it's more complicated than the text above...

I'm actually passing the filename to the page that's displaying the media from another page.  See, the user selects a video to watch, I grab the Video object and pass `video.filename` to the new page, which will display the video.

My original idea was this.  First, pass the video filename from the Page where the user selects a Video:

```
[RelayCommand]
private async Task NavigateToPlayMediaPage(Video video)
{
   string str = "embed://" + video.VideoFilename;  // "ThrowSource" is a string prop
   await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(PlayMediaPage)} ThrowSource={str}");
}
```

We catch the string on the Page where we display the Media, and we do this in the Xaml:

```
            <toolkit:MediaElement Source="{Binding CatchSource}"
                                  ShouldShowPlaybackControls="True"
                                  Aspect="AspectFill" />
```

Of course, it turns out that `Source` takes an object of type `MediaSource'.

OK.  So what I could do is create the `MediaSource` object from the passed-filename string.  I could create an "Appearing" method (that runs before the Xaml).  In that "Appearing" method, I could create the MediaSource:

```
using CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views;

namespace ems_mobile.ViewModel;

[QueryProperty("CatchSource","ThrowSource")]
public partial class PlayMediaPageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    string catchSource;

    [RelayCommand]
    private async Task Appearing()
    {
        var mediaSource = MediaSource.FromResource(CatchSource);
    }
}
```

And then I could use that MediaSource object in the Xaml:

```
            <toolkit:MediaElement Source="{Binding mediaSource}"
                                  ShouldShowPlaybackControls="True"
                                  Aspect="AspectFill" />
```

Alas, that doesn't work. I'm just getting a white screen.  No player. No error. The problem is in the "Appearing" method I don't actually have access to the passed-string.  I guess "Appearing" methods don't get passed strings or something.

=======================================================================

EDIT: Getting weird exception.  If I can figure this out, I should be good.

I'm passing the Media Source object from the `SelectMedia` page to the `ViewMediaPage`.  It's passing correctly with the correct values.

Here it is, enjoying itself in the method where it gets passed:
[image]

And here it is on the other side, the cheeky bugger, values intact:
[image]

Here's the xaml -- it looks good to me:
[image]

The only problem... when I get into the `ViewMediaPage`, this happens:
[image]

================================================================
**FINAL EDIT** how Ï got it to work.

I had that exception message *you must implement `IConvertible`*.  So I did.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76409887/invalidcastexception-when-using-maui-shell-navigation-and-passing-an-object-to-p) a link that explains it. I had created the `MediaElement` object needed for the `Source`, only I didn't pass it from the previous Page correctly.

That link shows a great way to pass as many objects as you like from one page to another, pretty hassle-free.  The only problem is you can't access the passed objects from an `Appearing` method because the `Appearing` method runs before the implementation of the `IConvertible` interface, which does the "catching" of the objects.

Comment: Yes, [it is](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/blob/7dd409e95d91babcf7d90d0657c5557f75b058bd/src/CommunityToolkit.Maui.MediaElement/MediaElement.shared.cs#L75)

Comment: I'm realizing that the problem is that I was trying to put a String into the Source attribute, when it should've been an object type MediaSource.  So... I need to figure out how to create that, too, and then figure out this binding thing you referenced.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75525722/correct-way-to-set-net-maui-mediaelement-source-from-code

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, but I haven't been doing any C#-for-Xaml, so I'm a little lost.  That's ok -- I just need to keep backing up until I find something I understand and go forward from there.  Happy biking!

Comment: You’re binding to a C# MediaSource property, that code shows you how to create that object

Comment: use `MediaSource.FromResource()` to load an embedded resource

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, but I can't get the syntax correct or something.  Here, I'll edit my question and show you.

Comment: My original question was simple.  The reality is a little more complicated... but it's still a very-likely very-common scenario.

Comment: You can only bind to public properties.  mediaSource is a local variable that will go out of scope as soon as the method completes

Comment: Also, I’d guess that FromResource expects a resource name, not a url

Comment: I realized that about the local scope, so I actually declared it as an `ObservableProperty`, which didn't change anything because I don't have access to that string in the Appearing method.  That's the problem.  I'm also passing FromResource a resource name (that is, a filename), not a URL.

Comment: I also tried to pass a MediaSource from the previous page to the page that is displaying the video.  That seemed like a great idea, but it didn't work.  It yelled that I didn't implement the `IConvertible` interface, meaning that it thinks I'm calling something the wrong type.  Which I can't find.

Comment: “embed://…” is a url.  There are numerous articles about how resource names work in C#.  Why can’t you use CatchSource in Appearing?

Comment: Oh yeah, I dropped the "embed" thing... I've actually been trying everything with and without it.

Comment: About not having access to the string in Appearing... I don't know.  I've never been able to catch a passed string in Appearing.  I didn't think it was possible. (Me and my week-and-a-half expereince in MAui.)

Comment: Start by hard coding the resource name in the call to FromResource.  Get that to work first, then worry about passing it from the other page

Comment: That's a good idea.  I will do that.

Comment: [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3089/Understanding-Embedded-Resources-in-Visual-Studio) has a good overview of the naming pattern

Comment: Oh, cool.  Yeah, I'm gonna read that.

I'm getting close.  I can get the MediaSource object with the correct "FromResource" value into thje XAML (see edits).  I'm getting an exception that I can't figure out, but if I can, I should be good.

Comment: @Jason GOT IT!  Man, you are THE BEST!!!  Thank you!  Here was my problem.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76409887/invalidcastexception-when-using-maui-shell-navigation-and-passing-an-object-to-p

Answer (score 0):

Using [.NET MAUI Community Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/), you could achieve this with an `ObservableProperty` in your *ViewModel*:

```
[ObservableProperty]
string audioURL;
```

And then add the Data Binding logic from your *View*:

```
MyMediaElement.Bind(
        MediaElement.SourceProperty,
        nameof(MyViewModel.AudioURL),
        convert: (string url) => MediaSource.FromUri(url));
```

If you are interested to see it in action, I have written a series of articles about the MediaElement. You can start from [here](https://www.mauicestclair.fr/en/posts/tutos/my-first-app/10-play-music-with-mediaelement).